# PHP Update data to sql

Tags: php, mysql

In order to insert some data to mysql I use:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (fullname, email) VALUES ('John Doe', 'john@example.com')";
```

But I'd like, before that, if the fullname `John Doe` for example is already used in a query of MyGuests table then that to be updated with the e-mail. If not, then data to be inserted normally like above. How could I do that? Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you using mysql_* or mysqli_* functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check rows using mysql num rows. Use the code below

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MyGuests WHERE fullname='John Doe'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO MyGuests (fullname, email) VALUES ('John Doe', 'john@example.com')");
}
else{
mysql_query("UPDATE MyGuests SET email='youremailname@name.com' WHERE fullname='John Doe'");
}
```

If you are using mysqli_* functions then replace mysql with mysqli. I am not using prepared statement , you have to use them to stop sql injection. I suggest you to use PDO or mysqli prepared statements to stop sql injection.
Hope tis helps you

Answer (score 0):

You have to query MySQL first to check if there's any results already and if so run a UPDATE query instead of INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `on duplicate key update` like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyGuests (fullname, email) VALUES ('John Doe', 'john@example.com') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE email='john@example.com';
```

for this to work as expected make sure that fullname is the primary key.